# Custom view render after scrollViewDidEndZooming

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have CustomView with code in drawRect like this:

> for var i = 0;  i < m; ++i
>
> ```
>     {
>         // just draw lines
>         UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
>         let line = UIBezierPath()
>         line.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y:0 + CGFloat(i) * cellWidth))
>         line.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: size.width, y:0 + CGFloat(i) * cellWidth))
>         line.closePath()
>         line.stroke()
>     }
> ```

In **scrollViewDidEndZooming** i'm trying to do something like customView.setNeedsDisplay() and redraw the view to make last one look good, but result appears this way (lines have different widths):

[image: odd lines]

How to make this good?

Comment: `line.lineWidth = scale * k` slightly helps, but i think there must be better decision

Answer (score 0):

** drawRect** is a heavy method that gets called continuously. It's generally considered a bad practice to add lines inside it.

The reason you're getting this is that the multiple lines are getting drawn on same location, so it appears as if they've different widths.

Inside **scrollViewDidEndZooming**, check you scroll view's content offset and set it to CGPointZero if it's not (0,0).

Hope this helps..

Comment: Judging by log in **drawRect** in debuger it gets called rarely enough, are you sure this function draws continuously?

Comment: It'll be called whenever you call 

    [customView.setNeedsDisplay]

So there might be some lines getting drawn again & again on the same location.